# Harden Joomla 3.1 Login Form

Tags: joomla3.1

I try to add additional security to the login forms by requiring a security token via URL parameters (GET). Authentication should be refused if the token does not match the configured one. The URL is something like site.com/administrator?security=12345

Up to Joomla 2.5 that worked fine and URL parameters were accessible via JRequest::getVar('parameter_name') or JURI::getInstance($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])->getVar( 'parameter_name').

In Joomla 3 this does not work any more. Posting the form only submits the form itself. Any other data is removed, even if the URL originally did contain parameters.

Any ideas about how I can read the full URL including the parameters when submitting the login form? Thanks

(On the Joomla forum this question never received any reply.)

Comment: Have you tried or looked at this extension? It looks like the thing you're looking for, or you have to build your own plugin but using Joomla! 3 JInput and not JRequest. http://www.jproextensions.com/index.php/shop-downloads/plugins/jprocheckin?bc

Comment: Thank you Mario, JInput give the same result. The URL parameters are not available any more. (By the way, breaking out of the framework does not help either. The PHP globales are cleaned too) The extension you mention is commercial, but this is a good idea. I'll check how other plugins work...

Comment: Followup: I found one plugin that seems to do something similar. It is a system plugin though (not authentication) and it is triggered onAfterInitialise. Then it also tries to get the URL params via JRequest. Maybe at that stage the environment is still intact. Checking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is intentional or not, but JRequest::getVar() works fine in system plugins but not in authentication. 
Therefore I will adjust and create a system plugin that checks if a page request is for a login and apply the additional security measures if that is the case.